# python memcache search string

Tags: python, linux, memcached

any idea how i can search a string in memcache,i have a list of domains which are loaded onto memcache

what i would like to do is search a string on those domains...

```
[root@server python]# cat memtest.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import memcache
domain = "http://www.yahoo.com/images.txt"
s  =   memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
def addData():
    proc = open("domains.txt","r")
    for i in proc.readlines():
        d = i.rstrip("\n");
        s.set(d,1)

def getData():
    name = s.get("yahoo.com")
    print name
    name = s.get("xaa.com")
    print name
    ##dummy code, just an example
    if domain in s.get(domain):
        print found


def main():
    addData()
    getData()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def addData():
    proc = open("domains.txt","r")
    for i in proc.readlines():
        d = i.rstrip("\n");
        s.set(d,d)


def getData():
    name = s.get("yahoo.com")
    print name
    name = s.get("xaa.com")
    print name
    ##dummy code, just an example
    if s.get("yahoo.com"):
        if domain.find(s.get("yahoo.com")) > 0:
            print found
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a value from memcache, you have to know the exact key under which the value was stored.

```
s.get("yahoo.com")
```

will work only if

```
s.set("yahoo.com", <some value>)
```

was executed before.

looks like you don't know the exact keys because they're being retrieved from a file. 
You can try using a regular expression to get the base domain from the file, and make sure "yahoo.com" is used as a key.